# cucumber not recognising steps when Play is enabled

Tags: scala, playframework, cucumber

With a sample sbt application, when I put in the features in src/test/resources and the steps in src/test/scala, it works well. When I enable play and add the following line to build.sbt, it stops recognising the features and steps

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

If I add 
cucumberFeaturesLocation := "src/test/resources"
to the build.sbt file, it picks up the features but still does not find the steps.

This is how my plugins.sbt looks

```
 resolvers += "Templemore Repository" at "https://templemore.co.uk/repo/"

addSbtPlugin("templemore" % "sbt-cucumber-plugin" % "0.9.0-SNAPSHOT")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "3.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.9")
```

And my build.sbt is shown below:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test",
        "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "1.1.5"
        )

seq(cucumberSettingsWithTestPhaseIntegration : _*)


cucumberFeaturesLocation := "src/test/resources"
```

If I remove the enablePlugins line, it picks up the step files, but they fail compilation because it does not find play libraries. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You could try adding `"info.cukes" % "cucumber-scala_2.10" % "1.2.2" % "test"` to your build.sbt instead of using the sbt-cucumber-plugin. See http://www.sebnozzi.com/82/cucumber-and-play/ for an example setup to work with play, scala and cucumber.

Comment: Tried adding that, but did not help. Moving the Step definitions from src/test/scala to test directory in the root of the project helped. Adding play  seems to make the test path change to ./test instead of src/test/scala